# Operation with double with comma or dot

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So I have three TextBox (weight, height and result) in my XAML and in my C# I have this:

```
float final = float.Parse(weight.Text) / (float.Parse(height.Text) * 
float.Parse(height.Text));
result.Text = final.ToString("n2");
```

In TexBox weight and height, the user can insert number with dot or comma, but the result only appears correct if the user use dot.
Why are different?

I need the result to be the same with dot or comma.

Thank you!

Comment: In different cultures, the dots and the commas mean different things. If you want to force one to become the other....well you know how to use `string.Replace()` I hope? You'd have to be careful that there's not multiple dots or commas in there....

Comment: This should allow for period to be the decimal separator on a compute that is set with a culture that does that and a comma for cultures that use that as the decimal separator.  Alternatively you can force it to use one or the other, but it's best to let the person choose the way they want to enter numbers.

Comment: Also you might want to use `float.TryParse` in case the user enters an invalid value.

Comment: Do you want to allow both a thousands separator and a decimal separator? Note that, for example, in the US a comma is the thousands separator and the period is the decimal separator, but in Italy it's the opposite (and some cultures use spaces).

Comment: What if the user entered `1,002`? Does that mean "one thousand and two", or "one and two thousandths"

Answer (score 0):

A hotfix would be to use

```
weight.Text.Replace(",",".");
```

Same for height of cause.

Comment: That wouldn't work very well if someone entered "1,000.35"